# Finding files in linux based on regex, with multiple alternatives

Tags: bash, regex, shell-script

Let's say I have a list of strings. I want to find files with filenames starting with these string.

Example,

Strings:
filename.could.start.with.this.restoffilename
a.file.could.have.this.at.beginning.restoffilename

This list of strings can be an arbitrary number (obviously much more than just two as above).

I want to use a bash script for this and only use what I consider basic linux applications (ls, grep, sed, find etc.), so no python, perl, ruby or other such languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prefixes=("filename.could.start.with.this" "a.file.could.have.this.at.beginning")

# Turn the prefix array into a find expression (in array form)
matchlist=()
for prefix in "${prefixes[@]}"; do
    matchlist+=("-o" "-name" "$prefix*")
done
matchlist=("${matchlist[@]:1}") # remove the extra "-o" from the beginning

# Search the current directory for plain files with names starting with one of the prefixes
find -x . "(" "${matchlist[@]}" ")" -type f
```

If your list of filename prefixes wasn't in array form, you'd have to modify this appropriately, e.g.

```
prefixes="filename.could.start.with.this a.file.could.have.this.at.beginning"

...
for prefix in $prefixes; do
...
```

Also, this will not behave well if given an empty list of filename prefixes; if that's a possibility, check for this condition first.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. However, I'm getting an error on the -x flag on find. I can't see any -x in man find either.

Comment: @Mikael: that's a flag that (at least on my version) keeps `find` from crossing volume boundaries.  I had a bad experience once (accidentally scanning an entire server volume), so I tend always use it unless I specifically want to search multiple volumes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I use "find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2" straight from ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @Mikael: it looks like findutils doesn't implement this (or several other options I'm used to from the BSD version), but you can get the same effect with the `-xdev` primary (i.e. `find . -xdev "(" "${matchlist[@]}" ")" -type f`).

Answer (score 0):

[BASH FAQ entry #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Just keep adding `find` predicates to the array until you have your command.